# Is it possible to click on element by testRigor Path?

Tags: python, selenium, element, testrigor

I want to click on element using **(testRigor Path)** which I got from Selectors hub extension. is this possible?
Note I can't click it on any other way since the xpath and css selector are changing frequently thus testRigor will be the best option (I am using python seleinum for that) and here's the element's outerhtml

[image: testRigor]

```
<a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-hidden="true" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;LV&quot;}" id="cvf_phone_cc_native_112" class="a-dropdown-link" style="" xpath="1"><span>Latvia </span><span dir="ltr">+371 </span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In testRigor, you'd probably be better off using what's visible to the end user; in this case, either Latvia or +371.0.

`click "Latvia"` or `click "+371.0"`

Although, the testRigor path contains both of those values, they are separate nodes, and testRigor doesn't concatenate them.